# Count points in each quadrant of a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatterplot

I'm an R noob, please bear with me.

I'm using R to plot data in a scatterplot along with 2 gridlines separating the plot into 4 quadrants. I'd like to count the number of data points in each quadrant. How might I do this?

Comment: Beauty! @hxd1011

Answer (score 2):

The `table` function in R provide us a simpler way of doing the same thing as @Mark White suggested.

A simpler code `table(x>0, y>0)` will build a 2D table of the on four quadrants.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define what the values determining the quadrants are (here, `x` = 0 and `y` = 0), you can use the operators `<`, `>`, and `&` to get values that are TRUE or FALSE if the case lies in that quadrant. Since R stores TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0, you can simply sum across these to see how many are in each quadrant. Try this:

```
set.seed(1839)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

plot(x, y)
abline(h = 0)
abline(v = 0)

quadrant_1 <- sum((x < 0) & (y < 0))
quadrant_1
quadrant_2 <- sum((x > 0) & (y < 0))
quadrant_2
quadrant_3 <- sum((x < 0) & (y > 0))
quadrant_3
quadrant_4 <- sum((x > 0) & (y > 0))
quadrant_4
```

Comment: +1 for answering most basic (and probably off topic) question.

Comment: @hxd1011 off-topic, but fun and simple question

Comment: '`table(x>0, y>0)` most R way of doing it :)

Comment: haha, darn it, that's... a much better way of coding it...